I created a GUI for my Powershell script. How can I get the drag and drop field to work?
This is a script that creates a pop-up window that converts Office files for users in my company. I can't seem to get the drag and drop function to work. Does anyone know how to fix the drag and drop section so that it is functional?
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

# Ensure the script runs in STA mode
if ([System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.ApartmentState -ne [System.Threading.ApartmentState]::STA) {
    [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.SetApartmentState([System.Threading.ApartmentState]::STA)
    [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start([System.Diagnostics.Process]::GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName, '-sta')
    exit
}

# Create the form
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Text = "Legacy Office File Converter"
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(400, 320)
$form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

# Create the label with instructions
$instructionsLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$instructionsLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(360, 20)
$instructionsLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, 10)
$instructionsLabel.Text = "Select .xls, .doc, or .ppt files to convert to .xlsx, .docx, or .pptx"
$instructionsLabel.TextAlign = [System.Drawing.ContentAlignment]::MiddleLeft

# Create the list box to display selected files
$listBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox
$listBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(360, 100)
$listBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, 40)
$listBox.AllowDrop = $true
$listBox.DragEnter += {
    param($sender, $e)
    if ($e.Data.GetDataPresent([Windows.Forms.DataFormats]::FileDrop)) {
        $e.Effect = [Windows.Forms.DragDropEffects]::Copy
    }
}
$listBox.DragDrop += {
    param($sender, $e)
    $files = $e.Data.GetData([Windows.Forms.DataFormats]::FileDrop)
    $listBox.Items.Clear()
    $listBox.Items.AddRange($files)
}

# Create the label to display the current file being converted
$statusLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$statusLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(360, 30) # Increased height for better visibility
$statusLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, 150)
$statusLabel.TextAlign = [System.Drawing.ContentAlignment]::MiddleLeft

# Create the progress bar
$progressBar = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar
$progressBar.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(360, 20)
$progressBar.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, 190)
$progressBar.Minimum = 0

# Create the button to open file dialog
$selectButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$selectButton.Text = "Select Files"
$selectButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100, 30)
$selectButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, 220)
$selectButton.Add_Click({
    $fileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    $fileDialog.Multiselect = $true
    $fileDialog.Filter = "Office Files (*.xls;*.doc;*.ppt)|*.xls;*.doc;*.ppt"
    if ($fileDialog.ShowDialog() -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK) {
        $listBox.Items.Clear()
        $listBox.Items.AddRange($fileDialog.FileNames)
    }
})

# Create the "then..." label
$thenLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$thenLabel.Text = "then..."
$thenLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100, 30)
$thenLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(150, 220)
$thenLabel.TextAlign = [System.Drawing.ContentAlignment]::MiddleCenter

# Create the convert button
$convertButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$convertButton.Text = "Convert!"
$convertButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100, 30)
$convertButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(270, 220)
$convertButton.Add_Click({
    $files = $listBox.Items
    $progressBar.Maximum = $files.Count
    $progressBar.Value = 0
    foreach ($file in $files) {
        $statusLabel.Text = "Converting: $file"
        $extension = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($file).ToLower()
        switch ($extension) {
            ".xls" {
                $excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
                $workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($file)
                $newFile = [System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($file, ".xlsx")
                $workbook.SaveAs($newFile, [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat]::xlOpenXMLWorkbook)
                $workbook.Close($false)
                $excel.Quit()
                [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel)
                Write-Host "Converted: $file to $newFile"
            }
            ".doc" {
                $word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
                $document = $word.Documents.Open($file)
                $newFile = [System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($file, ".docx")
                $document.SaveAs([ref] $newFile, [ref] [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat]::wdFormatXMLDocument)
                $document.Close($false)
                $word.Quit()
                [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($word)
                Write-Host "Converted: $file to $newFile"
            }
            ".ppt" {
                $powerPoint = New-Object -ComObject PowerPoint.Application
                $presentation = $powerPoint.Presentations.Open($file, [Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState]::msoFalse, [Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState]::msoFalse, [Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState]::msoTrue)
                $newFile = [System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($file, ".pptx")
                $presentation.SaveAs($newFile, [Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpSaveAsFileType]::ppSaveAsOpenXMLPresentation)
                $presentation.Close()
                $powerPoint.Quit()
                [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($powerPoint)
                Write-Host "Converted: $file to $newFile"
            }
            default {
                Write-Host "Skipped: $file (unsupported file type)"
            }
        }
        $progressBar.Value += 1
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100 # Small delay to ensure the progress bar updates
    }
    $statusLabel.Text = "Conversion complete!"
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Conversion complete!")
})

$form.Controls.Add($instructionsLabel)
$form.Controls.Add($listBox)
$form.Controls.Add($selectButton)
$form.Controls.Add($thenLabel)
$form.Controls.Add($convertButton)
$form.Controls.Add($progressBar)
$form.Controls.Add($statusLabel)

# Show the form
$form.Add_Shown({$form.Activate()})
[void]$form.ShowDialog()


Copilot has spit out several different versions of the script, and none of them have worked so far. I'm a bit new with Powershell and don't have access to the tools that are typically recommended for adding a GUI to Powershell applications.
Here is the error in the console:
The property 'DragEnter' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At line:29 char:1
+ $listBox.DragEnter += {
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException
 
The property 'DragDrop' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At line:35 char:1
+ $listBox.DragDrop += {
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException


the pwsh equivalent to c# listBox.DragDrop += (sender, e) => ... is $listBox.Add_DragDrop({ ... })

As an aside for anyone who might be trying to work with MS Office legacy file formats. If your MS Office security prevents you from opening legacy Office formats in the first place take a look at the wordconv.exe and excelcnv.exe tools that come with Office. They can update Word and Excel files to latest format (except macro-enabled files) without needing to open those files in Word/Excel. They aren`t thoroughly documented (to put it mildly) but could be a useful last resort.

Thank you very much for the comments! I was able to get that working with that small change.
